# Is it possible to use SQL window functions with Jasper ReportServer?

Tags: oracle, jasper-reports, jasperserver, window-functions

Question about Jasper ReportServer 5.1 and its DomEL (Domain Expression Language).

I have a Domain with just one table. **T** is a table, (**day** date, **value** number) are columns with their types in Oracle.

So, if I try to make new "Calculated Field" in my Domain with expression:

```
first_value(value) over (order by day)
```

error message appers:

```
Found 'over' after end of expression
```

The main reason I think:

http://community.jaspersoft.com/documentation/sql-functions

Quote:

**You may use SQL functions** in a DomEL expression, but only in limited circumstances:

•   The functions must be supported by the database. See the vendor documentation for available functions and their syntax.
•   The functions must follow the **convention of comma-separated parameters**. For example, you can use TRIM(person.name), but not TRIM('Jr' FROM person.name)
•   The type of the return values must be appropriate, either within the expression or for the type of the calculated field.
•   The SQL context must be appropriate for the functions. For example, you cannot use aggregation functions such as COUNT in a calculated field because there is no GROUP BY clause.
**Except for the comma-separated parameter pattern, the DomEL validation cannot enforce** these criteria. You must ensure that any SQL functions meet these criteria, otherwise the expression causes errors when using the Domain to create a report.

Is my problem the result of this "enforcement"?

How can I use SQL window functions to construct calculated field?

Is there any way in Jasper to achive first_value/last_value/lead/lag effect?

Thank you!

Comment: I'm not familiar with Jasper, but I assume as a last resort you can always put the logic in a view.

Comment: Thank you, jonearles, but I can't do this, because date range depends of user input. If I decide to put logic in a view, I must agree that result doesn't depends of the period selected by user. So, no profit of using last_value or any window function at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is absolutely impossible. Very sad.